# How to get post reactions using linkedin marketing 2022 API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to get the list of reactions for linkedin post (called **share** in linkedin namespace)
the reference documentation is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/reactions-api?view=li-lms-2022-12&tabs=http

NOTE: I am using marketing API December 2022

I am trying to get the post on my own test page where i am an admin.

List of permissions my token has are: SCOPE = "r_organization_social,w_member_social,r_1st_connections_size,r_organization_admin,r_ads_reporting,r_emailaddress,r_basicprofile,r_ads"
as it says in above mentioned documentation, the first one **r_organization_social** should be enough.

in documentation it says:
`GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/(actor:{personUrn|organizationUrn},entity:{shareUrn|ugcPostUrn|commentUrn})`

for example organization_urn = urn:li:organization:12345678
and post urn = urn:li:share:7028701695735914497

how does the correct query looks like?

- api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/urn:li:share:7028701695735914497
- api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/(entity:urn:li:share:7028701695735914497)
- api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/entity:urn:li:share:7028701695735914497
- api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/urn:li:organization:12345678,urn:li:share:7028701695735914497
- api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/(urn:li:organization:12345678,urn:li:share:7028701695735914497)
- api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/(actor:urn:li:organization:12345678,entity:urn:li:share:7028701695735914497)
- api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/actor:urn:li:organization:12345678,entity:urn:li:share:7028701695735914497
- api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions?q=entity&entity=urn:li:share:7028701695735914497

etc...

most of those queries return error:
`{'status': 403, 'serviceErrorCode': 100, 'code': 'ACCESS_DENIED', 'message': 'Unpermitted fields present in RESOURCE_KEY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/reactionsId]'}`

or maybe I am missing something?

i can retrieve a summary or even list of likes and comments using socialActions endpoint, but that list does not contain the reaction type.
by the way the socialactions endpoint is pretty straightforward:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/urn:li:share:7028701695735914497' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {INSERT_TOKEN}'
-H 'LinkedIn-Version: 202212' \
```

returns a summary of likes and comments

`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/urn:li:share:7028701695735914497/likes` returns list of likes objects with authorids

`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/urn:li:share:7028701695735914497/comments` returns list of comments objects

Comment: Are you using the correct API? It seems you want all reactions for a particular share, regardless of the actor, so you would use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/reactions-api?view=li-lms-2022-12&tabs=http#get-reactions-on-a-share. Be sure to include the query parameters. The API you first referenced is for getting a reaction on a share by a certain person or org.

Answer (score 0):

":" to %3A

api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/(entity:urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A7028701695735914497)

and finally add Param q=entity

api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/(entity:urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A7028701695735914497)?q=entity

That worked fine for me ... after some trying due to the facts that the documentation is missing the ?

Comment: Please use this info to make your post look like you mean it to. Inlcuding to avoid the misunderstanding that this is a question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Doing this worked for me:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/(entity:urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A{share_urn_id})?q=entity&sort=(value:REVERSE_CHRONOLOGICAL)&count=1000
```

Don't forget to increase the `count` to get all your reactions.

Comment: I'm getting `{"message":"input %28entity%3Aurn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A7115296423415300096%29 is not a Compound key","status":400}` this error, do someone now why that's happening?

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: I'm trying to get reaction from the test post. I'm doing `/reactions/(actor:urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A96409721,entity:urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28activity%3A7115998576463216640%29)` and getting `{
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "status": 500
}` error. When I'm trying to send `/rest/reactions/(entity:urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A7115998573757894656)?q=entity&sort=(value:REVERSE_CHRONOLOGICAL)&count=1000` it gives me {"message":"input %28entity%3Aurn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A7115998573757894656%29 is not a Compound key","status":400}, I don't really know what is the problem